# My php code is giving error ,Why?

Tags: php

```
<?php 

  switch($_GET['select1']) {    
     $forecast = file_get_contents("https://www.astrospeak.com/horoscope/taurus");
     //error appears here when I am assigning forecast page a value else the code was 
     //working fine for simple switch statements.
        case 1:
            echo $forecast;
            break;
        case 2:
              echo '<div id="msg">Taurus, You have a bright luck today <br>';
            break;
         case 3:
             echo '<div id="msg"> Gemini, You have a bright luck today <br>';
            break;
        case 4:
             echo '<div id="msg"> You have a bright luck today <br>';
            break;  
         case 5:
             echo '<div id="msg"> You have a bright luck today <br>';
            break;
        case 6:
             echo '<div id="msg"> You have a bright luck today <br>';
            break;  
         case 7:
              echo '<div id="msg"> You have a bright luck today <br>';
            break;
        case 8:
              echo '<div id="msg"> You have a bright luck today <br>';
            break;
         case 9:
              echo '<div id="msg"> You have a bright luck today <br>';
            break;
        case 10:
             echo '<div id="msg"> You have a bright luck today <br>';
            break;  
             case 11:
             echo '<div id="msg"> You have a bright luck today <br>';
            break;
        case 12:
             echo '<div id="msg"> You have a bright luck today <br>';
            break;
        default:
           echo '<div id="msg">Bad Choice <br>';
            break;

    }
?>
<html>
 <div class="options">
    <form method="get" action="?" >
      <select name="select1">
          <option value="1">Aries</option>
          <option value="2">Taurus</option>
          <option value="3">Gemini</option>
          <option value="4">Aries</option>
           <option value="5">Cancer</option>
           <option value="6">Virgo</option>
           <option value="7">Libra</option>
           <option value="8">Scorpio</option>
           <option value="9">Sagittarius</option>
           <option value="10">Capricorn</option>
          <option value="11">Aquarius</option>
          <option value="12">Pises</option>
       </select>
      <input type="submit"  value="Go"\>
    </form>
  </div>    
</html>
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: you could also improve your code by using array and putting all the zodiacs in it. It will remove the redundant codes in your switch case because its seems all zodiac signs have a good luck

Answer (score 1):

Move the `$forecast = file_get_contents("https://www.astrospeak.com/horoscope/taurus");` before `switch` statement or inside `case 1`. Cannot add it between `switch` and `case`